# Closed form of $a_{k+2} = 4a_k + c^2$ when $c$ is some constant.

Tags: recurrence-relations, contest-math, closed-form

What is the closed form of $a_{k+2} = 4a_k + c^2$ when $c$ is some constant.

How can we find the closed form of this recurrence with constant? Usually , I’ll use the characteristic root technique, but now there’s some constant. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that if $b_k  := a_k  - a_{k - 1}$ then $b_{k + 2}  = 4b_k$. Also $$
a_n  = a_0  + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {b_k } .
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giben $$a_{n+2}-4a_n=c^2~~~~~(1)$$
Let us first solve $a_{n+2}=4a_{n} ~~~~(2) \implies x^2=4 \implies x=\pm 2$. So the solution of (2) is $a_n= C_1 2^n +C_2 (-2)^n$
For (1) let $a_n=A$, we get $A=-c^2/3$.
So the soluttion of (1) is
$$a_n=C_1 2^n+ C_2~ (-2)^{n}-c^2/3$$